# OpenCV 3.0 printing Mat

Tags: opencv, histogram

I am a newbie to OpenCV, so pls bear with me.. I am trying to dump the histogram Mat object for the given image.. It fails with the below error - Any help appreciated...

***The first cout in the below program i.e of the loaded image prints successfully - While the second cout of the hist of the image fails with the below error***

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (m.dims <= 2) in FormattedImpl, file /mycode/ws/opencv/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/core/src/out.cpp, line 86
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /mycode/ws/opencv/opencv-3.0.0-beta/modules/core/src/out.cpp:86: error: (-215) m.dims <= 2 in function FormattedImpl
```

Here is the complete code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: opencv.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    string imagePath = (argv[1]);

    cout << "loading image..." << imagePath << endl;

    Mat image = imread(imagePath, 1);

    Mat hist;

    int imgCount = 1;
    int dims = 3;
    const int histSizes[] = {4, 4, 4};
    const int channels[] = {0, 1, 2};
    float rRange[] = {0, 256};
    float gRange[] = {0, 256};
    float bRange[] = {0, 256};
    const float *ranges[] = {rRange, gRange, bRange};
    Mat mask = Mat();

    calcHist(&image, imgCount, channels, mask, hist, dims, histSizes, ranges);

    cout << image << "Loaded image..." << endl;
    cout << "Hist of image..." << hist;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if the Mat hist is initialized when you leave the calcHist() function body?

Comment: If I do something like this - It does print something   void printMatrix(Mat mnd) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                cout << setprecision(11) << mnd.at<float>(i, j, k) << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OpenCV 2.4.9 source code:

```
static inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const Mat& mtx)
{
    Formatter::get()->write(out, mtx);
    return out;
}
```

Is the function you are calling when using `<<` operator. `Formatter::get()` returns appropriate 
formatter class based on the programming language you are using.

`write()` function basicly calls:

```
static void writeMat(std::ostream& out, const Mat& m, char rowsep, char elembrace, bool singleLine)
{
    CV_Assert(m.dims <= 2);
    int type = m.type();

    char crowbrace = getCloseBrace(rowsep);
    char orowbrace = crowbrace ? rowsep : '\0';

    if( orowbrace || isspace(rowsep) )
        rowsep = '\0';

    for( int i = 0; i < m.rows; i++ )
    {
        if(orowbrace)
            out << orowbrace;
        if( m.data )
            writeElems(out, m.ptr(i), m.cols, type, elembrace);
        if(orowbrace)
            out << crowbrace << (i+1 < m.rows ? ", " : "");
        if(i+1 < m.rows)
        {
            if(rowsep)
                out << rowsep << (singleLine ? " " : "");
            if(!singleLine)
                out << "\n  ";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see if your `Mat` dimensionality is greater than 2 assertion will be thrown like in your code (`CV_Assert(m.dims<=2)`).

`calcHist()` with the parameters you gave produces 3-dimentional `Mat` and thus it cannot be displayed using `<<` operator

By calling `calcHist()` function that way you are getting 3-dimentional histogram and I don't see a simple solution to visualize that in OpenCV (which doesn't mean it can't be done). If it's something you must do I would suggest to look into OpenGL for 3D data visualization. If not you could simply call this function for each channel seperatly - you will get 3 one-dimenational histograms which you can print using `<<` operator.